# NavigationLink is not working on Custom defined Button SwiftUI iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I've have defined a custom button in my SwiftUI file as following.

```
struct CircleButtonWithIcon: View {
    
    @State private var navigateToHomePage = false

    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(20)
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3607843137, blue: 0.003921568627, alpha: 1)))
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3)
                )
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to navigate to next page as following.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeView: View {
    
    @State private var navigateToHomePage = false

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Image("WelcomeBackground")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("No Worry,")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text("Handle")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("Your Hunger,")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                Text("With")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            Text("Eattak!")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                                        
                            Text("Eattak come to help you hunger problem with easy find any restaurant")
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.white).padding().multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                            CircleButtonWithIcon()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom,100)
                }
                
            }.background(
                Image("welcome-black-shadow")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            )
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        }
     }
    }
}
```

I have added `NavigationView` and inside that add `NavigationLink` but on the button click it's not navigating to the next page.

> I've reviewed all of the questions but none of them helped

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `NavigationLink` is meant to be used with `Button` here. Try replacing the button view in `NavigationLink` with just its label (the image):

```
NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(20)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3607843137, blue: 0.003921568627, alpha: 1)))
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3)
            )
    //Removed CircleButtonWithIcon()
}
```

I hope this helps.